# Single Photon/Electron Emitter

Tags: materials, design, optics, experimental-physics, electronics

Is it possible to buy single photon/electron emitter in market for experimental purposes? If yes, can you please guide me where and how?

Comment: Shopping questions are not allowed. See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.